# Python regex to PHP?

Tags: php, python, regex

I'm trying to convert a Python script into PHP.

The following 2 regular expressions work in Python:

```
'/\*\*([\w\n\(\)\[\]\.\*\'\"\-#|,@{}_<>=:/ ]+?)\*/'
'(?:\* ([\w\d\(\),\.\'\"\-\:#|/ ]+)|(?<= @)(\w+)(?: (.+))?)'
```

...however, if I try to run them in PHP I get:

```
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier ']'
```

How come?

Comment: You have to use proper delimiters http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. The first character is always treated as delimiter. So PHP interprets the first expression only until `<>=:/` and then finds the `]` which is not a valid modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that PHP expects delimiters around its regexes, so it treats the first and second slash as delimiters and tries to parse what follows as modifiers.

Surround your regex with new delimiters and try again (I also removed some unnecessary backslashes):

```
'%/\*\*([\w\n()\[\].*\'"#|,@{}_<>=:/ -]+?)\*/%'
'%(?:\* ([\w\d(),.\'"\:#|/ -]+)|(?<= @)(\w+)(?: (.+))?)%'
```

Hint: Use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) to do these things. It will take a regex written in language A and convert it to language B for you.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE (including `preg_match_all`) requires a pattern boundary.  You need to wrap the entire pattern in `/`, `@`, `#`, `%`, or many other possible options.  I suggest `%` as it doesn't look like you are using it in either pattern, that is:

`%(?:\* ([\w\d\(\),\.\'\"\-\:#|/ ]+)|(?<= @)(\w+)(?: (.+))?)%`

Comment: Ha -- got it! I was using '/', but it's actually used inside the pattern!